# How to change a username in Informix?

Tags: sql, informix

How can I change a username in `Informix`?

`select * from sysusers;` lists below

```
username  John.Doe
usertype  R
priority  5
password
defrole   admin
```

I want to update the username to be in lowercase for user `john.doe` but seems we cannot just run an update on it `update sysusers set username = xxx` as usual. What command should we use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Someone ran:

```
GRANT RESOURCE TO "John.Doe";
```

You will need to to revoke their RESOURCE privilege:

```
REVOKE RESOURCE FROM "John.Doe";
```

but that leaves John.Doe with CONNECT privilege, which you will also need to revoke.  If you revoke DBA privilege from someone, they retain CONNECT privilege too (and not RESOURCE privilege).

```
REVOKE CONNECT FROM "John.Doe";
```

Then you can re-grant the RESOURCE privilege to the user name in lower-case:

```
GRANT RESOURCE TO "john.doe";
```

Note that the username must be quoted each time, both to conserve case-sensitivity and because neither `john.doe` nor `John.Doe` is a valid identifier because of the `.` in the middle.

These changes only affect the SysUsers table.  Any resources created by `John.Doe` are still owned by `John.Doe` and not by `john.doe`.  There is no way to change the ownership of objects.  The 'workaround' is to drop and recreate the objects with the correct owner.  Beware that dropping an object loses all permissions granted on the object, and also destroys views built on top of the dropped table (or view).

Comment: Does the Informix version make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Despite the catalog table name, entries in that table represent the Informix database level privileges for that user, not the actual user. It is the `GRANT` and `REVOKE` SQL commands that manipulate those entries.

The only way I can think is to `REVOKE` all database privileges for user `John.Doe`and `GRANT` the same privileges to the user `john.doe`. Note that any object owned by user `John.Doe` will continue to belong to `John.Doe`.